# How to handle update event without changing anything in a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid, with inline editing.
I click on "edit" button, and change some values; on update button click, i handle the event in this way (datasource configuration):

```
transport: {
       update: {
                type: method_attribute,
                url: update_url,
                dataType: data_Type,
                contentType: mime_charset,
                complete: function (e) {
                   // here I handle the update event ............
                } 
}
```

now, i need to handle the same event (on update button click), even if no values is changed in the row..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update will not fire unless some value is changed.

1) Change "dirty" property, which you can find on any dataitem. This will make the update fires.

```
datasource.data()[0].dirty = true;
```

use [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit) event to get hold of the dataitem

```
 edit: function(e) {
   e.model.dirty = true;
  }
```

2) Id the handler is not related to the actual update of the data, I would probably add onclick event at the actual update button, just to keep it separately.